# red5 error when starting - multiple bindings in class path

Tags: red5

Regarding red5

Greetings,

QUESTION:
I'd like to know how to remove the extra binding?

DETAILS:
I've installed red5 using the google codebase trunk... When starting red5 with the start script or manually ./red5.sh  it is giving this error:

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/red5/dist/red5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/red5/dist/lib/logback-classic-0.9.26.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

When I read at that link:

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Multiple bindings were found on the class path 
SLF4J API is desinged to bind with one and only one underlying logging framework at a time. If more than one binding is present on the class path, SLF4J will emit a warning, listing the location of those bindings. When this happens, select the one and only one binding you wish to use, and remove the other bindings.

For example, if you have both slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar and slf4j-nop-1.6.1.jar on the class path and you wish to use the nop (no-operation) binding, then remove slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar from the class path.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I've googled but can't find information on HOW TO remove the binding. Can someone please tell me how to remove one of those binds from the class path?

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer...

I used zip7 to remove the class: StaticLoggerBinder.class

in:  /lib/logback-classic-0.9.26.jar!

Answer (score 0):

This is only a informational message created by slf4j; people shouldn't be concerned with it. We haven't found an easier way to provide separate red5 application logging without our custom binder as of yet. Our binder is what causes this message and while your fix will prevent the message, you'll have to perform this action with every slf4j library update.

Answer (score 0):

As http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings (now?) explains, you should exclude this SLF4J binding when declaring the unscrupulous dependency in your project's pom.xml file.